# Access violation .Net c# in the client's machine - Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed a C# .Net (4.0) application (using Crystal Reports) in computer 1, when i copy this application's executable to computer 2 (.Net framework 4.0 well installed) this application won't start.

i've checked the task manager : my application's memory use was increasing to attempt 2048 ko and then it stopped immediately, 2 seconds later, the process get killed .

i've used OllyDBG in computer 2 to debug/check the problem, i've get an "access violation" while starting the application

i faced some exceptions, skipped them, and finally access violation to stop all the iterations in the ollyDBG

(even if i made a blank form in computer 1, and copied the executable to computer 2, it works well)

After testing this application in computer 3 (.Net 4.0 well installed) a window has appeared : applicationxxx has stopped working .

---

i don't think that i've to install VS in the client's machine to run this app

Please is there any way to track the bug ?
thanx a lot

Comment: Do you mean blank form works ok on computer 2? If so, please post some additional information about your application - it's hard to guess, what can cause the problem.

Comment: Yes a blank form, or u can say a new empty project to test if the computer 2 can run .Net apps or not

Comment: Ok, please add some information about original application.

Comment: Do you have any monitoring or logging in your application? Do you have some dependencies to libraries? Tell more about your application!

Comment: i've already checked the crystal reports needed dlls, they are all present, a quick screenshot : http://i.imgur.com/r9yUzo5.jpg

Comment: Have started your application on your computer from a different path with the release version? Perhaps you could try http://www.netomatix.com/development/DependsNet.aspx

Comment: the application works from any path in my computer

Comment: what do you have as required framework? which one is installed on the other computer?

Comment: .Net 4.0 is installed in both machines

Comment: Full, the problem is how to find a way to export all needed DLLs, dependancies etc ... (Not manually)

Answer (score 0):

installing CRRedist2005_x86.msi in the client's machine will solve the problem,

in fact without this framework, i've got "the application has stopped working" without any indication to any missing assembly